# Classic ASP - Stored procedure to recordset returns "-1" records?

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I am trying to execute a stored procedure using Classic ASP, with two parameters and return the results into a record set that I can loop through and display into a table via a DO WHILE loop.

The problem is, however, I do not get any results when I try and execute the below code. When I use the "RecordCount" property it returns -1 records.

Normally if it were a standard SQL query I would use Response.Write to get the query text and diagnose in SSMS, but i'm not sure how I can troubleshoot when using ADODB.Command. Is there a way to write out exactly what it is doing?

Here is what I have:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
With cmd 
    .ActiveConnection = objConn 
    .CommandType = 4
    .CommandText = "dbo.testCount" 
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Location", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50))
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@Year", adInteger, adParamInput))
    .Parameters("@Location").Value = "TestLocation"
    .Parameters("@Year").Value = 2014
    Set objRS = cmd.Execute()
    End With
    Set cmd = Nothing
    TotalRecords = objRS.RecordCount
    Response.Write TotalRecords
```

^^^^ TotalRecords = "-1" .. ?

Comment: check this: http://www.adopenstatic.com/faq/recordcounterror.asp

Comment: Also make sure you have set [`SET NOCOUNT ON;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx) in your stored procedure if you don't want closed recordsets to be returned along with your expected recordset.